# Call app.js function in route file Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

In app.js I have a function I want to call from a routes file.

This is simplified of course.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var foo = function() {
  return 'bar';
}

module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
?
```

I tried to require('../app.js') and call app.foo but that didn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to call `foo` from outside `app.js`? What you have at the moment is a module that exports an instance of express...

Comment: @Tholle I open a sqlite database in app.js and want to have a function on the server that performs queries and returns the results on a route call.

Comment: @James yeah call foo from outside app.js

Comment: I see. Would it not be beneficial to create a separate module, e.g. sqlite_utils.js, and simply require this in your routes file instead?

Comment: @Tholle never thought of that.  I'm new to all this. Ill give that a shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to export both `app` and `foo` then you could export an object surfacing both

```
module.exports = {
    app: app,
    foo: foo
}
```

Or alternatively, you could do

```
module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.foo = foo;
```

Then in your routes

```
var app = require('../app').app,
    foo = require('../app').foo;
```

Comment: Thanks, now how would I call foo in the routes?  foo( );?

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut yes, the module exports the function `foo` from the `app.js` file so you would just call it like any normal function.

Comment: I keep getting undefined is not a function for foo();

Comment: Do you actually have a function called `foo` in app.js?

Comment: Yeah, var foo = function() { return 'bar'; }

Comment: I'm gona stab a guess at either the path to `app.js` being wrong (does `app.js` actually reside in a folder *above* `routes.js`? Because that's where you are looking).

Comment: routes folder and app.js are on the same level

Comment: Then your path should be './app' not '../app'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83455/discussion-between-norcalknockout-and-james).

Comment: ./ would mean app.js is in the same folder as index.js